# Using Elm Json.Decode to move vales from parent to child record

Tags: elm

I'm writing an elm json decoder, and want to move a value from a 'parent' record into a 'child'.

In this example I want to move the `beta` key/value to live in the `Bar` type.

My incoming JSON

```
{ "alpha": 1,
  "beta: 2,
  "bar": {
    "gamma": 3 
  }
}
```

My types

```
type alias Foo =
  { alpha : Int
  , bar : Bar 
  }

type alias Bar =
  { beta : Int 
  , gamma : Int 
  }
```

How can I do that in a decoder? I feel like I want to pass the decoder for `beta` down to the `fooDecode`. But this clearly isn't right...

```
fooDecode =
    decode Foo
        |> required "alpha" Json.Decode.int
        |> required "bar" barDecode (Json.Decode.at "beta" Json.Decode.int)

barDecode betaDecoder =
    decode Bar
        |> betaDecoder
        |> required "gamma" Json.Decode.int
```

Note: My actual use case has a list of children, but hopefully I'll be able to work that out with a pointer on this. I'm using Decode.Pipeline as it's a large JSON object

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Json.Decode.andThen` here to parse `"beta"` and then pass it on to `barDecode` and `Json.Decode.Pipeline.custom` to make it work with the pipeline:

```
fooDecode : Decoder Foo
fooDecode =
    decode Foo
        |> required "alpha" Json.Decode.int
        |> custom
            (Json.Decode.field "beta" Json.Decode.int
                |> Json.Decode.andThen (\beta -> Json.Decode.field "bar" (barDecode beta))
            )


barDecode : Int -> Decoder Bar
barDecode beta =
    decode Bar
        |> hardcoded beta
        |> required "gamma" Json.Decode.int
```

With this change,

```
main : Html msg
main =
    Html.text <| toString <| decodeString fooDecode <| """
{ "alpha": 1,
  "beta": 2,
  "bar": {
    "gamma": 3
  }
}
    """
```

prints:

```
Ok { alpha = 1, bar = { beta = 2, gamma = 3 } }
```